# Как реализовать слайдер с миниатюрами в owlСarousel 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

Подскажите примеры, как реализовать слайдер на owlСarousel 2, а к нему миниатюры карусели owlСarousel 2
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

Можно сделать примерно вот так

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  dotcount = 1;

  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    margin: 10,
    nav: false,
    autoHeight: true
  });
  
  $('.owl-dot').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('dotnumber' + dotcount);
    $(this).attr('data-info', dotcount);
    dotcount = dotcount + 1;
  });

  slidecount = 1;

  $('.owl-item').not('.cloned').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('slidenumber' + slidecount);
    slidecount = slidecount + 1;
  });

  $('.owl-dot').each(function() {
    grab = $(this).data('info');
    slidegrab = $('.slidenumber' + grab + ' img').attr('src');
    var slide = '<img src="' + slidegrab + '">';
    $(this).append(slide)
  });

  amount = jQuery('.owl-dot').length;
  gotowidth = 100 / amount;

  $('.owl-dot').css("width", gotowidth + "%");
  newwidth = $('.owl-dot').width();
  $('.owl-dot').css("height", newwidth + "px");

});
```

```css
.owl-carousel {
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.owl-stage-outer {
  border: 5px solid;
}

.owl-dots {
  display: flex;
}

.owl-dot {
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item"><img src="https://www.floridagulfbeachrealty.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/cropped-Tom-Slaughter-Header-Media-Image-.jpeg"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRZvHgi67sLw1WfE7vNMx7JF1sr50bfU4mHTFG8nyPy1b3zXYec"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSAkXIOqHoHPOattE5Taft-Sr7McgV9jLE-n-Jx_Mv3OtyHidsD"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://cdn.newsapi.com.au/image/v1/06e4a0f5221e045e88ba3c707e1e7949"></div>
</div>
```